# Подскажите как сделать так чтобы выполнялось действие когда луч первым столкнулся с обьект с тегом "Player"

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы выполнялось действие когда луч первым столкнулся  с объектом с тегом "Player".Знаю как пускать лучи но не знаю как проверить когда луч первым столкнулся  с объектом с тегом "Player"

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
{
    if (hit.collider.tag == "Player")    
    {
        if (_firstRayHitObj == null)
        {
            _firstRayHitObj = hit.collider.gameObject;
            transform.Translate(0,0,000000000000002f);
        }
    }
}
```

Получается, выпускается луч если он попал в первый раз в объект с тегом player то объект передвигается на оси z.

Comment: Что значит "луч первым столкнулся с объектом"? Объект что ли не может столкнуться с лучом?

Comment: то есть должно выполнятся действие когда  произошло первое столкновение луча с обьектом         @ArtikSlayer

Comment: @ArtikSlayer доходчиво обьяснил

Answer (score 2):

Код не проверял, может не работать

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    RigitBody _rigidbody;
    float _speed = 10;
    GameObject _firstRayHitObj;

    void Start()
    {
        //инициализация нужных переменных, например _rigidbody.
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Player")    
            {
                if (_firstRayHitObj == null)
                {
                    _firstRayHitObj = hit.collider.gameObject;

                    _rigidbody.velocity = -transform.forward * _speed;
                    //Z-axis movement bazed on phisics
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для чего эта проверка `if (hit.collider != null)`? Ветка `if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))` сработает, если рейкаст попадет по коллайдеру, а если он попал, очевидно, коллайдер какой-то он задел.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker скопировал с оф.документации этот кусок

Comment: Ну документация не всегда права, это раз. Два: `bool True if the ray intersects with a Collider, otherwise false.`, `Physics.Raycast` не может вернуть true и при этом не увидеть коллайдер.

Comment: @Andrew вопрос а где проверка именно на первое столкновение

Comment: @danchikon10 добавил

Comment: @Andrew если не сложно можете обьяснить что вы дописали .

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mag3ks хотя вообще это же самое можно было сделать с `bool` переменной `IsFirstRayHitAlreadyDone` или `int` счетчиком `RayHitCounter`. Реализация не важна в даном случае, она больше зависит от конкретных твоих потребностей, кои мне не известны.

Comment: @Andrew  а   нужно  в _firstRayHitObj вписывать какой либо обьект и можете код посмотреть он в правке если что

Comment: @Andrew upppppp